# Parse.com update Role error

Tags: parse-platform

I'm getting `{"code":101,"error":"object not found for update"}` when calling *save* on my role after adding a user to it, all on Cloud Code.

Sample code:

```
var role_query = new Parse.Query('_Role')
role_query.equalTo('name', 'USER')
role_query.first().then(function(role) {
  role.getUsers().add(user)
  role.save()
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The error was that I didn't have permission to update the role.

Solution was using `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` at the beginning of the Cloud Code function.

In case you need to update roles on the client:

https://www.parse.com/questions/role-cant-assign-user-in-js